# Customize Sitecore Image Field Property Dialog

Tags: custom-field

I want to give a custom image field's property dialog a class dropdown. Currently I have a custom image field which points to a custom image control.

That control overrides `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image`'s ShowProperties method. The only line that I have really changed in that method is the line that has a namespace reference.

I have overriden it to point to a custom class that inherits from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.ImageProperties.ImagePropertiesPage`.

I'm getting the following error indicating that my class cannot be found:

> Xaml control "MyNamespace.CustomSitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.BrandedImageProperties.BrandedImagePropertiesPage, MyNamespace.Common" not found. The last error was: [No error]

The line I have changed is as follows:

```
    UrlString urlString = new UrlString(FileUtil.MakePath("/sitecore/shell", 
        ControlManager.GetControlUrl(
            new ControlName(
                "MyNamespace.CustomSitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.BrandedImageProperties.BrandedImagePropertiesPage"))
        )
    );
```

I'm assuming that's because it looks in Sitecore.Client. Is there any way to change this so it will look through a dll I specify? Is this even the right way to do something like this (override 1 dialog on a field by creating a completely new field)?

Comment: where is the control you created found? Because the above code, it will search for the control within the `sitecore/shell` folder. If you place your control within the `sitecore/shell/application/[custom folder]`, the above code may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have created your control and is present in the `website/sitecore/shell` or `website/sitecore modules/`.

Moreover, the namespace used in the code should match the one in the control, i.e, the xaml/xml file.

Comment: Yup I had copied the default xml file and didn't change the xml node inside it to match what was being looked up (https://www.screencast.com/t/YUkBgDp3f). Once I made that change it looked it up correctly. I do wish I could just make a command to open the dialog so I don't need to go through the hoops of overriding as much stuff as I did though.